# Android some mp4 file not getting shared on Whatsapp

Tags: android, share, mp4, whatsapp, aac

In my Android app I am trying to create a mp4 file by merging two different video and audio file. Video file is in .mp4 file format and audio file is in .aac format. The merged video file is in .mp4 file format and it is betting played via VLC player. But this file is not getting shared on WhatsApp. It gives error "Can't send this video. Choose a different video and try again".

In my Android app, there is another feature of downloading an mp4 file from our backend via https url. The downloaded file is also getting played via VLC player, but it also not getting shared on WhatsApp. It is also giving the same error as mentioned in above paragraph.

Below I am attaching screenshots from VLC player giving the details of the videos.
[image: This screenshot belongs to merged mp4 file][image: This screenshot belongs to downloaded mp4 file]

Comment: were you able to fix this shishir ?